# How to reduce the line size of Floating Label EditText when it is in active state

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here I am using Floating Label EditText.  I need to edit the size of the line under the EditText when I enter any text into that text field. Here I have added the code for your reference

This is the code in XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_last"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_last"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:theme="@style/MyEditTheme"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:hint="Password" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This my style.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyEditTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
        <!-- Used for the bottom line when not selected / focused -->
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#383838</item>

        <!-- colorControlActivated & colorControlHighlight use the colorAccent color by default -->
    </style>


</resources>
```

Here I need to reduce the size of the blue line.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you mean the text size of Email/phone Number?

Comment: use `app:counterOverflowTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small"` in `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` tag. Add `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in root tag.

Comment: @am110787 OP says several time in the question "need to edit the size of the line". Your code will affect text size of red error character counter. What the hell?

Comment: I asked him this question

_Do you mean the text size of Email/phone Number?_

and he responded **yes**